# python list prefix each string item and append

Tags: python, list

**How can I do this in shorter way:**

```
vmt = ['title', 'designation', 'company', 'address', 'city', 'country']
vmt_copy = []
vmt_copy[:] = ['old-%s' % item for item in vmt]
vmt[len(vmt):] = vmt_copy
vmt = '|'.join(vmt)
```

**Above script outputs:**

`'title|designation|company|address|city|country|old-title|old-designation|old-
company|old-address|old-city|old-country'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'|'.join( vmt + map( lambda m: 'old-'+m, vmt) )
```

Which is essentially what you have.

Edit:

Dont know why this didnt occur to me earlier -

```
'|'.join(vmt) + '|old-' + '|old-'.join(vmt)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vmt.extend('old-%s' % item for item in vmt[:])
```

You must use a copy of the list so that you don't create an infinite loop of prepending and adding.